# Бонапарт/бонапарт

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, имена-нарицательные

В первых абзацах и далее в тексте «Призрака театра» (А. Дмитриев, «Знамя» 6, 2003), на мой взгляд, известная фамилия несправедливо даётся со строчной. Вопрос: может быть такое, что она перешла в разряд существительных нарицательных?

> Любой режиссер — бонапарт, сказал мне один сценарист. Так это кинорежиссер. Сидит себе на барабане: «Массовка пошла! Танки пошли! Кавалерия пошла! Самолеты пошли! Батарея — огонь! Из всех стволов — пли! Пара на заднем плане — целуется!». Театральный режиссер, по моим многолетним наблюдениям, не бонапарт, а метрдотель.

Answer (score 4):

В общих сведениях к правилам употребления прописных и строчных букв (ПАС под ред. Лопатина, [**§ 158**](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp158.php)) имеется вот что:

> Имена собственные могут использоваться для обобщенного обозначения однородных предметов, становясь нарицательными; при этом прописная буква во многих случаях заменяется строчной.
> <...>
> Собственные имена исторических лиц, литературных или мифологических персонажей, употребляясь обобщенно (переносно) как названия людей с определенными чертами характера и поведения, пишутся неединообразно — одни со строчной, другие с прописной буквы. Их написание, определяемое традицией употребления, устанавливается в словарном порядке. Так, слова *донкихот, донжуан, робинзон, держиморда, иуда, меценат, геркулес,* употребляясь в нарицательном смысле, пишутся со строчной буквы, а *Гамлет, Обломов, Манилов, Плюшкин, Хлестаков, Митрофанушка, Аполлон, Цицерон, Наполеон* и многие другие сохраняют при этом прописную букву.
> <...>
> **Примечание.** Написание личных имен со строчной буквы (обычно в форме мн. ч.) допускается как экспрессивно-стилистический прием, чаще всего с целью усиления отрицательной или иронической оценки лица: *современные чичиковы, азефы, робеспьеры, новоявленные геббельсы* и т. п.

Вполне возможно, что Андрей Дмитриев ***намеренно*** использовал такой — особенный — прием (я не читала книгу, поэтому могу только предполагать).
Отнесем "строчного бонапарта" к авторской орфографии, тем более что прецедент есть.

*Срок удалось увеличить до одного месяца, по истечении которого пришлось покинуть прекрасную Францию с ее **бонапартами**, большими и маленькими* (Е. А. Соловьев-Андреевич. Александр Герцен. Его жизнь и литературная деятельность (1897)).

Comment: Прецендента — *бонапарта* в словаре — не видел. Но благодарю за развёрнутый отклик. Пока можно утверждать, что А. Дмитриев зачинателем доброй традиции не стал.

Comment: Под прецедентом я подразумевала авторскую орфографию — написание со строчной буквы. И привела соответствующий этому использованию пример. У Толстого, кстати, тоже есть: *...в Древней Греции и Риме было более свободы и равенства, чем в новой Англии с китайской и индийской войнами, в новой Франции с двумя **бонапартами** и в самой новой Америке с ожесточённой войной за право рабства.* Правда, в разных источниках — по-разному.

Comment: Так ведь у  Толстого и Герцена слово во мн. числе, а это, как сказано в примечании, дело обычное.